# R: how to replicate the <<- assignment with assign()?

Tags: r, global-variables, variable-assignment

I need to assign a variable in a function, whose name is a parameter of the function, and I need to access it later on, outside the function. I think `<<-` would do it in another situation, but since the name of the variable is dynamic, I think I need `assign()`.

What I have at the moment

```
assignVar = function(varname) {
     assign(varname,"blabla")
}
assignVar("foo")
foo
```

returns the usual `Error: object 'foo' not found`.

Is there some  option to the `assign` function, or any other secret weapon, that I could use to do that? I have looked at the documentation, but I am still very confused about environments... (R beginner).

Comment: Just don't do this.  You will save yourself much hassle by simply returning all variables you need in a list as the result of your function.

Comment: Try `assign(varname,"blabla", .GlobalEnv)` , though not recommended

Comment: @Andrie, I think you are right but I am not sure how to do that. What I need is a function that checks whether a RDS file exists and loads it in a variable (passed as parameter). If the file does not already exist, or needs to be recreated, the function executes an R script (whose path is passed as parameter) to generate the file, and keep it in memory.

In that situation, I can't really have `df <- checkLoad(dataset.path,scriptToGenerate.path)` because if the function runs the script generating the data (and in that script assign it to `df`), the command above would then overwrite `df`.

Comment: Unless maybe if the part of the function running the script finishes with `return(df)`, so that `df` would receive `df`.

Comment: You're asking a new question - and I suggest you indeed ask as a new question. I think we have answered your original. But why not just assign your result to `df_new` ?

Comment: I am dealing with quite big datasets so I do not want to overburden memory. This is why the script generating data and saving it to RDS does not remove the object from memory once it is done: to avoid removing then reloading the data.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question where you outline what you're doing an d ask for better approaches.  It's not clear to me what you're doing at the moment, but I can assure you I have never, ever had to use `assign()`.

Comment: @Andrie: I had started writing the question and found my solution in the process. The function now returns the value to be assigned, whether read by readRDS() or from a variable already loaded in memory. So the function itself does not try to do the assignment.  I just do `var <- assignVar(parameters)` and it seems to do what I want without overburdening memory. Thanks for suggesting it inyour first comment.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, but keep in mind that using `assign` should really be avoided. You're doing something strange. Be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest you don't do this:

```
assignVar = function(varname, envir = globalenv()) {
  assign(varname, "blabla", envir=envir)
  invisible(NULL)
}

assignVar("foo", envir=globalenv())
foo
[1] "blabla"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's really important to understand the behavior of `<<-` before you use it. Once you understand that behavior, you will also note that you cannot use `assign` to achieve its behavior (at least not very easily). Here's a simple example:

```
a <- 1
f1 <- function(){
    a <<- 2
    NULL
}
f1()
a
# [1] 2

a <- 1
f2 <- function(){
    a <- 2
    f3 <- function(){
        a <<- 3
    }
    f3()
    NULL
}
f2()
a
# [1] 1
```

`<<-` works by assigning into the parent environment, if possible. If there is no existing `a` object (in this example) there, it goes up another level and repeats this until it reaches the global environment, where it will ultimately assign if no other lower environment worked. So in the above examples, `f1()` results in a change to the global environment but `f2()` does not. If you comment out the `a<-2` line of `f2`, you do get a change in the global environment.

To achieve the same behavior using `assign`, you would need to write a much more complex function that loops through parent environments until it reaches the global environment. Regardless, having functions produce side effects is generally discouraged (due to introducing often unnecessary complexity to code and particularly when those side effects occur in the global environment).